# Windows 10 half speed Internet

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, internet-speed, all-in-one

My wife has an HP all-in-one 21-2024 that came with Windows 8.1. I upgraded the OS to Windows 10 a few weeks after the release date.

My wife has been complaining about how slow her Internet connection is for years and across many different pc's so I didn't pay too much attention until I was installing Office 365. That got me to go to speedof.me and run the test. We are on a 35Mbps plan with our provider. My desktop, my laptop, my phone, and several other devices in the house all get 25 to 30 mbps where as my wife's HP usually gets about 10 and absolutely will not download any faster than 15 according to speedof.me and speedtest.net.

Even though every other device in the network gets expected speeds I tried several different physical network configurations as well as changing up the settings in the router. All of this led to me running a cat 6 cable directly from the modem to the problem machine, disabling all unnecessary programs and services, updating the Ethernet driver first from HP then directly from the manufacturer. All of this and still no results.

The only thing I haven't done is trying to transfer a large file from another system in the lan to the HP. I'll hopefully get a chance to try that out this weekend.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I can try if the lan transfer doesn't indicate an issue with the hardware?

Comment: file transfer will probably not give better result. It is hard to help since you don't seem to have "before" data, so maybe it is not an issue with Win10. I wonder if [this Amazon review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R2QD14KB9C61HS/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B012DZTD2A&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=541966&store=pc) is from you :)

Comment: Yup, that's my review. I don't have any hard numbers from before the Win10 upgrade but my wife wasn't complaining about slow Internet browsing as much before the upgrade.  I guess I'll try reverting to Win8.1 and see if that helps, although it'll be a pain in the neck.

Comment: What NIC is in that box? Is it only a 10Mbps card?

Comment: Is the Cat6 a roll-your-own or off the shelf?

Comment: @Burgi http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04488999 says it's a Realtek RTL8151GH-CG with Transmission standards: 1000BASE-T Ethernet. Of course HP is sending me a free HD usb Webcam because all their fact sheets say the Webcam in the bezel is HD as well as a lot of the promo posters and packaging. So without cracking the case and reading it off the chip directly who knows?

Comment: @Burgi it's an off the shelf but I'm sure the cable isn't the issue. I used the same cable on my machine and got proper speeds, and I tried a couple of other cat 5e lengths 1 homemade and 1 store bought.

Comment: Just covering off the obvious bases. I know it is a crazy idea but is there any setting in the BIOS that limits the NIC connection speed?

Comment: I looked but I didn't find anything. I'm about ready to pay HP the $25 for the recovery Cd's and start from square one.

Comment: @DavidBumpus What about booting up Linux or something from a LiveDVD and test speed from there? This will narrow problem to BIOS/hardware

Comment: I tried a version of tails but I'm thinking because of all the encryption and privacy extras it was even slower. Any favorite distros to recommend?